# Is the code I wrote for my exercise efficient?

Tags: java, performance, diffie-hellman

I've learned to write code implementing the Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm below, but I feel that my code isn't at its most efficient. Can anyone correct my code please...?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.util.Random;;

    public class DH_key {
        static class DHGenParameterSpec implements AlgorithmParameterSpec{
            static BigInteger p;
            static BigInteger g;
            static int a,b;
            static BigInteger A,B;
        static BigInteger getPrimeP_G() {
            Random rand1= new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Random rand2= new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()*10);

            p= BigInteger.probablePrime(32, rand1);
            g= BigInteger.probablePrime(32, rand2);
            System.out.println(""+p+","+g);
            return null;
        }
        static int getExponent() {
            SecureRandom ranGen1 = new SecureRandom();

            a= ranGen1.nextInt(1000);
            b= ranGen1.nextInt(1000);
            System.out.println(a+"__"+b);
            return 0 ;

        }
        public static Object pow (){
            //g.pow(a);
            A = g.pow(getExponent()).mod(getPrimeP_G());
            B = g.pow(b).mod(p);

            return null;        
        }



    public static void main(String[]args){
        //System.out.println(DHGenParameterSpec.getPrimeP_G());
        DHGenParameterSpec.getPrimeP_G();
        DHGenParameterSpec.getExponent();
        A = g.pow(a).mod(p);
        B = g.pow(b).mod(p);

        BigInteger Sa,Sb;
        Sa=B.pow(a).mod(p);
        Sb=A.pow(b).mod(p);

            System.out.println(""+A+"__"+B);
                System.out.println(""+Sa+"__"+Sb);
        }

        }

    }
```

Was the code above appropriate with java rules??

Comment: thanks to all who is help me editing my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written modular exponentiation as:

```
        A = g.pow(getExponent()).mod(getPrimeP_G());
        B = g.pow(b).mod(p);
```

This is inefficient because the intermediate result from the exponentiation can be a large number. You should use the [`modPow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) method instead, which does the two operations with an efficient algorithm:

```
        A = g.modPow(getExponent(), getPrimeP_G());
        B = g.modPow(b, p);
```

Comment: i try to use modPow before..., the problem is getExponent must be an BigInteger, whereas i need integer value from getExponent()

Comment: You can use the `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` method to convert primitive integer types into `BigInteger`

Comment: thanks @Joni i change my code with modPow and converting primitive integer with BigInteger.valueOf(long) and it work..., thank you very much :)